# How to use RPC query in JavaScript with read method, for get all rows from table. In Odoo 13?

Tags: javascript, sql, database, rpc, odoo-13

i work with odoo 13. I trying get all the rows, from my table. What should I pass in my arg, for get all the string at once?

My code:

```
 var res = rpc.query({
            model: 'my model',
            method: 'read',
            args: [????]
        }).then(function (data) {
            console.log(data); });
        };
```

Comment: Have you already tried using empty parentheses?

Comment: @Alonso yes, i tred.

Comment: What I would try is to give as arguments some dummy conditions, something like "args: [[['id', '>', 0]]]".

Answer (score 1):

Павел Храпун

To call a `method` on a (python) `model` with having accessing the record data through RPC.

```
var id = this.id; // (pass the record of ID which you want to read the data)
var res = rpc.query({
        model: 'Your Model',
        method: 'read', // method which you wanna call
        args: [[id], ['name']], // First argument to pass the ID along with second args pass fields
    }).then(function (data) {
        console.log(data); });
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

the *args* can get context, domain and fields as parameters. to get all records, you should use empty domain and fields like :

```js
var res = rpc.query({
            model: 'my model',
            method: 'read',
            args: [[], []] // empty parameters
        }).then(function (data) {
            console.log(data); });
        };
```